# Can I set the Request Queue Name when using System.Net.HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, system.net, httpsys

I have a service that listens for HTTP messages via HTTP.SYS. It uses the [System.Net.HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-8.0) class:

```
this._httpListener = new HttpListener();
foreach(var prefix in _addressPrefixes.Select(ChannelIdToUrlPrefix))
{
    _httpListener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
}
_httpListener.Start();
```

I would like to set the name of the HTTP Listening Queue so I can identify it easily in the Performance Monitor. I can't see how to do this.

As an example of where I can see how to do this, I have another service which uses AspNet Core. This does allow me to set the name, via the [RequestQueueName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.httpsys.httpsysoptions.requestqueuename?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-server-httpsys-httpsysoptions-requestqueuename) option.

```
builder.UseHttpSys(
    options =>
    {
        //
        // Set all the other options as well
        //          
            options.RequestQueueName = "My Custom Name";
    }
);
```

Is there any way I can set the queue name when I am simply using the HttpListener class?